# How to install Lubuntu on Windows 98SE

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 14.04.5 LTS using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows CD image approach, and it's asking for the boot.ini file but it doesn't exist on Windows 98SE.

So you know my specs it has an Intel Celeron 533 @ ~530 MHz with 256MB of RAM. And everything else is set but that boot.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

`boot.ini` is a small file in the root of the system partition which is nearly always the `C:\` drive.

`boot.ini` is not normally visible in Windows Explorer as it has the Read-only, System, and Hidden attributes set.

[Source and more info](http://www.thpc.info/how/editbootini.html) about `boot.ini`.

Note:
[Recommended Minimum System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu Desktop:

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)

but

- A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are lower-spec than described above.